# IOS enterprise self distribution not downloadable

Tags: ios, enterprise

I am distributing my IOS app through enterprise account. I have hosted the html file on github and have placed the .ipa and plist files in google drives. Issue is my link (https://nylaa.github.io/) don't redirect me to download. Any help?

Comment: Google drives redirect you to drives website, it's not downloadable link

Comment: Its not even redirecting

Comment: try to use https://rink.hockeyapp.net/, it's very beautiful tool to distribute your app

Comment: I want my distribution free of registering UDIDs and this tool requires that registration

Comment: what is your developer account program? it's Enterprise?

Comment: Yes it's enterprise and I'm following this link https://www.goodbarber.com/blog/distribute-your-ios-app-out-of-the-store-with-the-apple-developer-enterprise-program-a871/ 

The part "Do you want to manage your app's distribution yourself?
"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179519/discussion-between-moayad-al-kouz-and-naila).

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with the url in my html file. After correcting that I was able to redirect to plist file, but there the issue was that it was showing text file instead of downloading ipa. I resolved that issue by installing SSL certificate.